# How to use href in HTML span when using TSX syntax?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to using Typescript and React so sorry if this is a novice question. In my code I have the following line:

`<p><span href="#" id="nsTool" style={{color:"white", width: "50px"}}> Namespace </span></p>`

This originally worked fine when the code was just using Javascript/React but when I converted the file to a .tsx (Typescript), I got the following error:

```
Type '{ children: string[]; href: string; id: string; style: { color: string; width: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>'.
  Property 'href' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>'.
```

Does this mean that I can't use href in the span element? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you able to explain why you would want to add `href` to a span?

Comment: I was following a tutorial and it was in the sample code. I removed it and it seemed to work fine, I'll make sure to understand all components before I implement it next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) elements only allow [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes). So the `href` attribute won't have an effect on `span` and therefore you get a Typescript error.

Note: The `href` attribute is usually only found on an [`anchor element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip. I was unaware that span elements can only allow global attributes. I ended up removing href attribute from the code since it wasn't actively being used.

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` tag does not have `href` attribute. You can append span tag with anchor tag like this way:

```
<span>
    :&nbsp; 
    <a href="#">
        Namespace
    </a>
</span>
```

Comment: I didn't realize that href is usually used in anchor tags. Thanks for the help!